# What is the difference between "context" and "with_context" in anyhow?

Tags: methods, error-handling, rust, closures, lazy-evaluation

This is the documentation for anyhow's [Context](https://docs.rs/anyhow/1.0.36/anyhow/trait.Context.html):

```rust
/// Wrap the error value with additional context.
fn context<C>(self, context: C) -> Result<T, Error>
where
    C: Display + Send + Sync + 'static;
```

```rust
/// Wrap the error value with additional context that is evaluated lazily
/// only once an error does occur.
fn with_context<C, F>(self, f: F) -> Result<T, Error>
where
    C: Display + Send + Sync + 'static,
    F: FnOnce() -> C;
```

In practice, the difference is that `with_context` requires a closure, as shown in anyhow's [README](https://github.com/dtolnay/anyhow/blob/f9419cd5a13496112deb0fac5386fc3c9fd5d60f/README.md):

```rust
use anyhow::{Context, Result};

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    // ...
    it.detach().context("Failed to detach the important thing")?;

    let content = std::fs::read(path)
        .with_context(|| format!("Failed to read instrs from {}", path))?;
    // ...
}
```

But it looks like I can replace the `with_context` method with `context`, get rid of the closure by deleting `||`, and the behaviour of the program wouldn't change.

What is the difference between the two methods under the hood?

Comment: If you take a look at the source code, it is exactly the same https://docs.rs/anyhow/1.0.36/src/anyhow/context.rs.html#42-60

Comment: I see. Are there any difference at runtime then? I don't see the benefit of having two functions for the same exact functionality.

Comment: The difference is that one evaluates your possibly quite complex context even if Result is not Err, while the other only calls the closure that creates the context when that context is actually needed. Which is exactly what the docs for `with_content` mention: Wrap the error value with additional context that is **evaluated lazily** only once an error does occur.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The closure provided to `with_context` is evaluated lazily, and the reason you'd use `with_context` over `context` is the same reason you'd choose to lazily evaluate anything: it rarely happens and it's expensive to compute. Once those conditions are satisfied then `with_context` becomes preferable over `context`. Commented pseudo-example:

```rust
fn calculate_expensive_context() -> Result<()> {
    // really expensive
    std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1));
    todo!()
}

// eagerly evaluated expensive context
// this function ALWAYS takes 1+ seconds to execute
// consistently terrible performance
fn failable_operation_eager_context(some_struct: Struct) -> Result<()> {
    some_struct
        .some_failable_action()
        .context(calculate_expensive_context())
}

// lazily evaluated expensive context
// function returns instantly, only takes 1+ seconds on failure
// great performance for average case, only terrible performance on error cases
fn failable_operation_lazy_context(some_struct: Struct) -> Result<()> {
    some_struct
        .some_failable_action()
        .with_context(|| calculate_expensive_context())
}
```

Comment: Question is more like, why did they call it this way? Could've been called "context_lazy" instead.

Answer (score 7):

As the documentation for [anyhow::Context::with_context](https://docs.rs/anyhow/1.0.36/anyhow/trait.Context.html#tymethod.with_context) states:

> Wrap the error value with additional context that is evaluated **lazily** only once an error does occur.

If what is passed to `context` might be computationally expensive, it is better to use `with_context`, as the closure passed is evaluated only when `with_context` is called. This is referred to as being evaluated in a *lazy* and not *eager* manner.

Similar behavior exists in the standard library, e.g:

| Eager | Lazy |
| --- | --- |
| [Option::or](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.or) | [Option::or_else](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.or_else) |
| [Option::unwrap_or](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or) | [Option::unwrap_or_else](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or_else) |
| [Option::map_or](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map_or) | [Option::map_or_else](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map_or_else) |