# Rust: Is there a way to shorten this if/else code using map?

Tags: rust

I am having a hard time how to use map as shown in this:

[Why does Rust need the `if let` syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27534364/why-does-rust-need-the-if-let-syntax)

Is there a way to shorten this code using map? I need the `else` part to work too but not sure how to do it with map?

```
fn token(&self) -> Option<String> {
    if let Some(token) = actix_web::HttpMessage::cookie(self,"token") {
        Some(token.value().to_owned())
    } else {
        None
        //Some("NO COOKIE!!!!".to_owned())
    }
}
```

Comment: `Some("NO COOKIE!!!!".to_owned())` <-- This is **not** how you should be using `Option<String>`.

Comment: What is your `token` function actually meant to accomplish? Why do you want to shorten it? (And why are you returning a `String` to represent an absent value?)

Comment: @Dai I am aware. In my actual code, it returns a `None` and not `No Cookie`. I will edit my question to have `None` instead. I just had `No Cookie` for demo purposes as I am still trying to learn Rust. This is just a demo function, it's not meant to accomplish anything - just trying to learn the use of `map`.

Comment: Have you looked into `Option`'s [`map_or()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map_or)?

Comment: @Jason thank you, that helped. I got it working using `actix_web::HttpMessage::cookie(self,"token").map_or(None, |t| Some(t.value().to_owned()))`. If you post this as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: That should be: `actix_web::HttpMessage::cookie (self,"token").map (|t| t.value().to_owned())`

Comment: I’m on mobile, but as @Jmb hinted at, if you still want to return `None`, one could use [`.map()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map) as it maps `Option<T>` to `Option<U>` and returns `None` when applied to `None`. This saves you from having to pass `None` as the `or` value when using `map_or`.

Comment: @Jmb thanks, I wasn't aware of that that feature of Map. Good to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to return a different value in the case of `None`, you can use `Option`’s [`map_or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map_or) or its *lazy* version [`map_or_else`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map_or_else).

```rust
fn the_answer(value: Option<u8>) -> String {
    value.map_or(String::from("Not the answer"), |n| format!("{} is the answer!", n))
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", the_answer(Some(42)));
    println!("{}", the_answer(None));
}
```

If you do not want to return a different value in the case of `None` and only want to map `Option<T>` to `Option<U>`, you could use `.map()` instead.

For more information on *eager* and *lazy* evaluation when deciding to use `.map_or()` or `.map_or_else()` the following might be of help:

- [What is the difference between “context” and “with_context” in anyhow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65459952/what-is-the-difference-between-context-and-with-context-in-anyhow/65460074)

Comment: thanks, I wasn't aware of that that feature of Map. Good to know.