# Rust: is there a way to shorten the `if/else` portion of the `from_request`?

Tags: rust

Is there a way to shorten the `if/else` portion of the `from_request`?

```
use uuid::Uuid;
#[derive(Debug)]
struct User {
    token: Option<Uuid>,
}

impl FromRequest for User {
    type Error = Error;
    type Future = Ready<Result<Self>>;
    type Config = ();
    fn from_request(req: &HttpRequest, payload: &mut dev::Payload) -> Self::Future {
        if let Some(t) = actix_web::HttpMessage::cookie(req,"token") {
            if let Ok(u) = Uuid::parse_str(&t.value().to_owned()) {
                futures::future::ok(User{token: Some(u)})
            } else {
                futures::future::ok(User{token: None})
            }
        } else {
            futures::future::ok(User{token: None})
        }
    }
}
```

Any way to remove the `futures::future::ok(User{token: None})` twice?

I tried to use `map` as shown in this:

[Rust: Is there a way to shorten this if/else code using map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65913261/rust-is-there-a-way-to-shorten-this-if-else-code-using-map)

but couldn't get it to work for the nested if/else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
fn from_request(req: &HttpRequest, payload: &mut dev::Payload) -> Self::Future {
    let token = actix_web::HttpMessage::cookie(req, "token")
        .and_then(|t| Uuid::parse_str(&t.value().to_owned()).ok());
    futures::future::ok(User { token })
}
```

Since you don't care about the error from parsing the `Uuid`, it calls `.ok()` which converts the `Result` into an `Option`. This lets you chain the optional values together with `and_then`.

Comment: You can also `use futures::future::ok` so you only have to call `ok`, though after using high-level combinators it's not much of a hassle anymore.

Comment: Thanks, `and_then` is new to me (rust newbie).